# Magnetic flux as a function of distance experiment

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, power, data-analysis

For my electrical engineering senior design I created an experiment to test magnetic flux (more voltage) increase from a material in a coil of wire. 
There is a large sending coil with A.C. voltage and a small receiving coil with an oscilloscope measuring voltage_pp. Its wireless power or those experiments were they light up an led from some distance. 
I ran three tests. One with the two coils, and two experiments with different metallic materials in the center of the receiving lens. Sort of a wireless transformer. I have results. I found online that flux has a 1/r^2 relationship. My results show a 1/x at almost the entire range of distances. When the two lenses are close I think mutual inductance comes in and stops the constant increase of voltage measured. If I plot voltage against 1/distance I definitely get a straight line. This would mean a 1/x relationship right? But online everywhere its 1/x^2. Also my large sending coil has a big radius which I'm wondering if that matters. If i take my slope from the straight line its voltage/(1/x) = voltage*x which is a weber? Or flux? I was really happy to see the slope are units of magnetic flux but I'm unsure. (its cm so not exactly weber but i can change to meters later) 
Big takeaway is why my results are 1/x and am interpreting the results of my slope correctly? I'm all on my own on this experiment, my group mates have done nothing lol and my prof has admitted to not knowing what wireless power transfer is about. Any help would be appreciated. (I have a capacitor on my receiving coil so the voltage induced can have zero impedance by sending the ac voltage at its LC resonant frequency. The tested material would change resonance but everything was in the range of 190kHz - 210kHz.)
[experiment I built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxdRX.jpg)[image: voltage vs distance]
[image: voltage vs 1/x]

Comment: you should review and explain what the $1/r^2$ flux relationship you are referring to.

Comment: your right almost everything online is in terms of B vs distance not flux. And B's strength vs distance depends on what making the field I guess.